# Why Java method has length like method().length?

Tags: java, stack-trace

I don't understand how the method can have length? method1().lenght. Following the same logic we can write main().length

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int stackTraceLength = method1().length;
        System.out.print(stackTraceLength);
        System.out.print(main().length);
    }

    public static StackTraceElement[] method1() {
        return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the method really has length? It returns an array - `StackTraceElement[]`, arrays have `length` property. The [tutorial from oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) should help to get you started understanding method return types.

Comment: In `method().length`, it's not the *method* that has a `length` property, it's what the method *returns* -- in this case, an array. Arrays have a built-in `length` property.

Comment: (Separately: That code won't compile, because of the call to `main()` later in the code, which is missing a necessary argument. Also, if that call to `main` from `main` worked, it would recurse infinitely -- well, until the stack ran out.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It also wouldn't compile because main has `void` as a return type, and thus has no `length` property.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - True. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method doesn't have a length property. The method you're calling returns `StackTraceElement[]`, which is an array, and arrays have a `length` property. In other words, you call the method `method1()`, it returns an array, and then `length` is called on that array.

It is the same as if your code was:

```java
StackTraceElement[] elements = method1();
int stackTraceLength = elements.length;
```

But just without the intermediate `elements` variable (also known as *chaining*).

The fact you can't call `main().length` has two reasons.

1. Your code doesn't have a `main()` method, it has a `main(String[])` method, so there is no method to be called
2. Assuming you meant something like `main(new String[0]).length`, that won't work because `main(String[])` has the return type `void`, which means nothing is returned, so there is no return value to call `length` on.